# Poner imagen de fondo centrada

Tags: html, css

Tengo un código `HTML` y mi deseo es poner una imagen como background del  y que esté centrada.

Este es mi código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      
    <style>
        body{
            
            width:30%;
            height:30%;
            margin:0 auto;
            background-size: cover;
            background-color:grey;
            background-image: url("logo.png");
            background-position: 50% 50%;
            
        }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

El problema es que me sale demasiado grande y alineada arriba de la pantalla, por lo tanto se corta en la mitad.

¿Alguna ayuda?

Comment: ¿Cómo esperas que sea el resultado final, podrías poner una imagen? ¿Cúal es el tamaño de la imagen logo.png?

Comment: @AlejandroRivas Nosé como poner una imagen, pero basicamente es poner al `<body>` una imagen de fondo y que esta imagen esté centrada. Las dimensiones de mi imagen son 500x500

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Funcionamiento

Cuando se agrega un background a un contenedor (como puede ser el body) los parámetros de fondo se agregan por css a través de las propiedades background-*. Sin embargo todas las demás propiedades ( como width o height )  son del contenedor, no del background.

Propiedades del fondo (más comunes):

- background-color: determina el color de fondo
- background-size: tamaño de la imagen, puede ser [cover, initial, contain, un %, un valor en px]
- background-image: url o fuente de la imagen
- background-position: posición de inicio con **respecto a su contenedor**
- background-repeat: ¿debe repetirse la imagen?

### Solución

Cuando pones la posicion como 50% 50% estas haciendolo con rspecto a su contenedor, como tu html esta vacio el contenedor apenas mide unos pixeles de alto, es decir tu imagen se coloca a la mitad de ese contenedor no de la pantalla:

[image: screenshot]

Bueno entonces tenemos que hacer el body más grande ¿pero que tan grande?... del tamaño de la pantalla. Como verás eso tiene varios inconvenientes, pero podemos hacerlo.

```
body{
        height: 100%; /*respecto a html*/
    }
html{
        height: 100%; /*respecto a la ventana*/
    }
```

Ahora tenemos contenedores que cubren toda la pantalla... pero hacen falta algunos ajustes al background:

```
body{
        background-color:grey;
        background-size: initial;
        background-image: url("logo.png");
        background-position:center center; /*respecto a body*/
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        height: 100%;
    }
```

- Ponemos el background-size en initial para que tome el tamaño original de tu imagen (puedes probar con contain)
- Definimos que el fondo no se va a repetir
- Y dejamos la posición en center center, que es igual a 50% 50% pero prefiero esta notación

#### Resultado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchisimas gracias Alejandro! Funciono correctamente!